# Bootstrap 3 Layout Assistance

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have downloaded the latest Bootstrap and copied the html on the bootstrap examples page for the layout called Carousel for a template for a page.

I then viewed this page using Firefox and everything looks great and is more or less a replica of the bootstrap carousel example page.

Underneath the carousel is a row of 3 columns. This row looks perfect in Firefox but in IE the last column drops down below the other 2 columns.

For the life of me, I just can't figure out what is going on with the CSS.

Comment: Give us a fiddle or some code to play with?

Comment: This is happening in IE v11

Comment: As soon as I have time I'll post details of a fiddle that I'll post.

Comment: Hey, finally figured it out. Wrong bootstrap.css was being loaded :)